# nslookup does not resolve hostname into IP address

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, dns

I have a Windows 7 machine on which I have a shared folder. I also have an all-in-one printer/scanner, and I'm trying to set up its scanner functionality to deposit scanned files into the shared folder.

The path to the network share and credentials ( This is on a domain, mind you )

**Example**

- *Path:* \\Examplecomputer1\scanner
- *username:* domain\username1
- *password:* sup3rs3krit

Except that doesn't work. Now, this does:

- *Path:* \\computer1ipaddress\scanner
- *username:* domain\username1
- *password:* sup3rs3krit

An IT guy started up an elevated PowerShell and tried this:

> nslookup examplecomputer1

&

> nslookup Examplecomputer1ipaddress

&

> Ping examplecomputeripaddress

&

> ping Examplecomputer

Hostname fails, IP address works. Other machines on the network work with both IP address and hostname.

I suspect a bad hostname or a bad DNS *something*, but I double checked the hostname settings and the DNS to rule that out.

Given these constraints, I'd like some suggestions on the issue...
This is all Windows 7. Network settings are all managed by the organization so please don't pursue anything that has to do with the infrastructure.

Comment: can you confirm that the 'hostname' binary and the system are using the same dns-server? the ping comand might be working because the dns-entry is still somewhere in the dns-cache. the hostname binary usually does not use the dns-cache. Can you confirm that whatever dns-server/domain server is configures is actually reachable? and has not been moved to another adress?

Comment: Good one, but, no. The domain's DNS servers are both reachable and the same for the printer and computer. Clearing the dns cache doesn't help either. Can't clear the dns cache on the printer, and a 2nd computer can't resolve it either. Clear cache or not.

Comment: Please post the output of `nslookup -d2 examplecomputer1`.

Comment: in your usage of nslookup are you passing the fully qualified domain name (myhost.example.org)?  Or just the hostname (myhost)?  What happens if you use the full domain name vs just the hostname?

Comment: Which DNS server are you using? If it is the domain's DNS server, does it have a record for this Windows 7 machine? If it does not have this record, it may request another DNS server to resolve, then it may resolve to a completely different IP address of this Windows 7 machine. Then you can’t access the share.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator It's a bit long and I really don't think I should. But thanks for the command. This should be helpful.

Comment: @Zoredache I'm not using a FQDN, just the computername. Using the FQDN results in the same problem.

Comment: @S.Leon I'm using the domain's DNS servers. I can't really check if the record exists, but I'm fairly confident it does, given how the machine has no other network issues.

Comment: You can change IP addresses and domain names in the output of the NSLookup command before you post it. The answer is in that output.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator The logs are huge. A lookup with just the hostname was bounced too and from all the way to the root servers! I don't think I'll find the computer name there! But hey, TTL = 1 day. Doing the same but with the FQDN "examplecomp.tree.forrest.local" limits the search to the domain but gives no useful answers.

Comment: @RicardoS. This only serves to confirm my suspicion that the answer lies in this output. The lookup should be handled by a DNS server hosting your domain's DNS records (often a domain controller). It sounds like that's not the case. How about posting the output of `ipconfig /all` (with necessary substitution of private details)?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator It's in Portuguese and heavily censored. Sorry I'm a bit paranoid.
[Link](https://imgur.com/a/gq0gDPI)

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator I get what you're driving at, but all the settings are handled automatically by the organization. I can't even change the DNS settings on the affected machine( I think it's a group policy forced on domain accounts). And when the infrastructure fails it all stops working. Not one odd machine. Though I find it possible that the DNS server records simply don't have the hostname for this machine's IP address.... Could have been a long time since the last refresh.

Comment: What happens if you run `nslookup Examplecomputer1.itsdomain.name IP_ADDRESS_OF_DNS_SERVER1` (Using the first DNS server listed in your ipconfig output)?

Comment: It say's that it can't find the the affected machine, non-existent domain.

Answer (score 1):

Most SMB implementations rely primarily on NetBIOS Name Service and WINS (not DNS) when trying to resolve unqualified hostnames into IPv4 addresses.

You need to make sure that the Windows 7 computer in question is registering the correct hostname to the WINS server (or advertising the correct hostname via NetBIOS Name Service broadcasts on the local LAN). It sounds like this machine is probably joined to the domain infrastructure since you're able to log into it via domain user accounts, but it sounds like maybe it's got its own hostname misconfigured.

Comment: Interesting take. Could it be the just the name being too long (over 15bits) and that's causing the issue? I think I'll try with a shorter name and see if it helps. 
It is indeed joined to the domain and suffers no other issues.

Comment: No such luck. New shorter hostname, reboot.  Same issue.